# set custom field value to other field of same object

Tags: trigger, custom-object, lookup

I am trying to set the value of one object in a custom object to be the same as the value of another object before deleting the first object. When I use the assignment operator, nothing happens although I'm certain that the Account__r of dbc is populated. Does anybody know why this doesn't work?

```
for ( Customer__c dbc : [SELECT Account__c, Account__r.Priority__c, Unique_Id__c FROM Customer__c WHERE Unique_Id__c IN :customers.keySet( )])
        {
            Customer__c c    = customers.get( dbc.Unique_Id__c );
            // replace the account of the last added customer if the priority is less
            // than that of the previous entry   
            // I could not find the solution to this problem. I cannot access
            // c.Account__r.Priority__c without using a DB call and could find no solution online.
            if ( accountMap.get( c.Account__c ).Priority__c.compareTo( dbc.Account__r.Priority__c ) 
                 < 0 )
            {
                c.Account__r = dbc.Account__r;
            }
            entriesToBeDeleted.add( dbc );
        }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: why are you using `< 0` in the compareTo(..) method? This doesn't test for equality; it tests for lexicographically precedes.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do that :) thanks.
Also I found my solution (for future references):
                             c.Account__r = dbc.Account__r;
should be:
                      c.Account__c    = dbc.Account__r.Id;

Comment: yes, of course -- good work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the c.Account__r, I should have used c.Account__c and I also should have used the c.Account__r.Id rather than c.Account__r.

```
c.Account__r = dbc.Account__r;
```

should be

```
c.Account__c = dbc.Account__r.Id;
```

maybe someone else is also struggling with this.

Comment: Jør, know that you should also be able to accept your own answer. This can be done by checking the (V) button on the left of your answer.